# Dynamic footer height based on UITableView Frame and ContentSize

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, footer

I'm trying to create a tableView in which has multiple states, some of them with footerViews that MUST fill out the remaining space the tableView.

I've been trying it using the TableView frame, and as well as the ContentSize. But turns out the ContentSize isn't right, and the footers are actually either smaller or larger than what I need them to be:

EstimatedSize for row:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            if myProperty != 0 { return 108 }
        case 1:
            if myProperty != 0, hiredRealtor { return 80 }
        default:
            break
        }
        return 0
    }
```

Height for Footer in Section:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            if myProperty == 0 { return UITableView.automaticDimension }
        case 1:
            if selectedRealtors == 0 {
                return tableView.frame.size.height - tableView.contentSize.height
            }
        default:
            break
        }
        return 0
    }
```

A wireframe of what I'm trying to achieve follows:

[image]

And then in my ViewForFooterInSection I use the same calculations in order to have the sameHeight, and it does. But it's not the correct height, because of ContentSize. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Table views are designed to scroll. Are you trying to create a non-scrolling table view? Or are you trying to create a table view with multiple sections, but you want each section to be the same height? So first section might have 5 rows + a short footer and second section might have 2 rows + a tall footer?

Comment: @DonMag, My tableView has multiple states, so sometimes it'll need to scroll, and other times it wouldn't have to scroll. Sometimes I'll just have 2 rows, and I want my footer to fill the rest. And some other times I'll have a fixed size footer with multiple cells. I simplified the code a little to be more was to understand :P

Comment: I'm guessing part of the problem is that the section footer views are part of the table view... which means you are changing the content size when you change the footer view size(s). Maybe if you show some example images of what you're really trying to do?

Comment: I thought that could be interfering as well, but since I don't have any estimated sizes for the footer, the contentSize should only be based on the cells. I'll update some screenshots of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So... what happens when you have, say, 5 rows, and only 6-pts of space for the footer view? Is it possible you will have 100 rows? Or are you generally expecting most of the table will be visible, with only occasionally having a couple extra rows to scroll? Maybe table view with section footers isn't the right approach...

Comment: I have 3 possible cases. 
1 - No cells at all: Shows a big footer (that works)
2 - N cells: Shows a small footer, with fixed height (that works too)
3 - Either 1 or 2 cells: Dynamic footer (this one doesn't work properly)